# How to setup idp_slo_target_url for ruby-saml (okta integration, saml2)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, saml-2.0, okta

hey i am trying to bind single logout functionality ok okta with my applications. I am using

```
gem 'ruby-saml'
```

But i am not able to get

```
settings.idp_slo_target_url =""
```

I have developer access for okta

I want to know what i need to set at  sp_issuer and signature_certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

Q: Does Okta support single logout / single sign-out (SAML protocol)?
A: No, Okta does not currently support single logout / single sign-out (SAML protocol).

Ref: http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/oan_guidance.html#okta-application-network-faqs